# Is it reasonable to use apache on my mac to be the game-server which people in my network can connect to and get information?

Tags: macos, apache, client-server, multiplayer

Not sure if its viable or reasonable idea. I'm new to this so forgive me if I forgot something simple. The idea is that I would have a game that could be played by multiple people in my network. What I want todo is make my local apache server listen for connection and handle game state logic to all listeners and update all listeners of for example the positions of each clients. Is this feasible? Currently I have my local apache setup on my mac. I can connect to my mac from my android device via inputting my ip-address. Any help on the next step? I would like to get a hello-world client/server program going using apache at least. Just need some guidance please.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the excellent [Apache portable runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad to be answered in this kind of a website.
If you're a developer and want to start developing online services with Java you can take a look at [my blog](http://amirzucker.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/creating-an-online-service-dont-start-from-scratch/), if you're into PHP you can find other blogs that can get you started.

Comment: Assuming I want to do this in HTML5, node.js, express.js do you have any high level guidelines I can follow?

Comment: I can't give you any specific advice on node.js and express.js as I don't know these frameworks, sorry.  What I can suggest is that you work in Continuous Deployment, and if possible use PAAS such as Cloudbees (or EC2 if you prefer to work lower level) which can be used for free if you're only starting out and don't need your server to always be online (Cloubees hibernates your service when it's not used.)  The point is:why host it out of your home machine when you can host online for free and be available to the rest of the world?

Comment: Oh nice, didn't even know about Cloudbees. Will look into it more. Thanks a lot man